# Debug vs. Release builds in the Android NDK

Tags: android, debugging, makefile, release, android-ndk

I'm working on a large game engine that must be ported to Android.  All the code is C/C++, so we are porting via the NDK.  I've got everything building, but after lots of scouring, I'm still uncertain what the best method is for building Debug vs. Release versions of our .so file.  Changing things by hand every time is getting old.

Do you have different Application.mk files for each target?  Or is there some way to include multiple targets in a single Android.mk file under the jni/ directory?  Or perhaps a third option might be to write a standard makefile that sets environment variables that the Android.mk file uses to inform the build process?

Finally, one last question regarding the android:debuggable flag that must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  What this actually have any effect on the generated native code that's copied to the device?

Best and thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Well, how do you choose Debug or Release by hand anyway? The NDK samples don't seem to have any debug or release flags, nor do they use an -Ox option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do you have different Application.mk files for each target?

No. Separate subdirectories, all with their own Android.mk (shared and static libs) but only one Application.mk for me.

My Application.mk is just:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

> I'm still uncertain what the best method is for building Debug vs. Release versions of our .so file. Changing things by hand every time is getting old.

It's a bit spread out, for me at least, using the jni/Android.mk + Application.mk layout.

Application.mk has `APP_OPTIM := debug`
Then in the application element of AndroidManifest.xml I have `android:debuggable="true"`
When you build with ndk-build, it uses this manifest flag to determine optimization (which is useful to turn off or on, off for profiling, etc.)

(A Little Off topic) I recently ran across

https://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/

Which, when combined with http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot

Generates some pretty images to help my little mind grasp how things are running over on the phone itself.

Comment: Yeah I've done all those things - what I ended up doing is having a different Application.mk for each target (release/debug).  Then in each file (Release.mk/Debug.mk) I specify global c flags via APP_CFLAGS and call ndk-build, specifying either Release.mk or Debug.mk from a standard makefile.

Comment: I find myself doing more profiling than debugging, and there are a few more flags to set/filter on a per-subproject basis (-fomit-frame-pointer and -pg are incompatible, for instance), so it's a bit more involved in my case as I don't want my entire lib chain to be -pg.

Answer (score 1):

You're not required to use the Android.mk system to build your .so's. Personally, I use my own Makefile's with the targets I need and this allows for very standardized debug vs. release build specification.

Comment: Do Android.mk files support multiple targets in a single file?  I'm hoping there's a way to salvage this using their system.

Comment: We also use our own build system (not the ndk), but be warned that this is a lot of work.  You'll definitely want to build some sample NDK projects and make sure you understand everything NDK is doing with compiler flags etc.  (We don't use the NDK stuff since we're doing many non-android builds too; using the NDK just for android is even more work than using our own build system for everything).

Answer (score 1):

I use a single file to build a library for diferent targets. In the Application.mk add this "APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a" it works for me.