# arm assembly code - understanding disassemble of cpp source

Tags: c++, arm

I have disassembled code in arm. I want to know the corresponding line number of these instructions in its original source file.

Also, I would like to understand few things.

a function for example say `android::CameraHardware::createInstance` is being shown in assembly as `_ZN7android18CameraHardware14createInstanceEib` . I am not even completely sure if this is the right function i am supposed to compare it with or not.

Why are names so strange and things are appended in front and back? I generally do the same for C code. There function names look straight forward in disassembled code.

So to summarize I have two questions.

- Inside GDB, is there a way i could get the line number of a
  particular line of assembly instruction?

  Say for example at 0x40d9078c, i want to know which line it
  corresponds to in its source file. I tried info line. No use. Any
  other suggestions?
- When we are understanding the disassembly of cpp code, how to
  understand the naming conventions? Also what other things we need to 
  understand as prerequisites?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: look at `extern "C"` if you miss your straight forward names

Comment: 1) Learn C++ name mangling. 2) learn a debugging symbol language (like DWARF).

Comment: Don't know about `gdb`, but you can use `objdump` with the options `-SCld` to get a disassembly mixed with the original source and line numbers, with demangled names.

Comment: @Michael Thank you so much. It is now a bit lcear for me. But however i cant see the source. But i am able to see the names demangled

Comment: You won't see the source unless you compiled with debug info. See Mats Petersson's answer.

Comment: @Michael The c++ source i mentioned is being built into a stripped shared library. It is being compiled in Android. So is it possible to use some flags in Android.mk which would enable the debug symbols?

Comment: You could try the suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589369/debug-vs-release-builds-in-the-android-ndk  (I haven't tested it myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation from `android::CameraHardware::createInstance` to `_ZN7android18CameraHardware14createInstanceEib` is called "name mangling", and is normal for C++. It is how you can have multiple functions with the same name, taking different parameters, and get the linker to tell you that "I couldn't find a `foo(int x, double y)`" when you only declared it, but didn't define it.

In Linux, you can use `c++filt` to translate a mangled name to its unmangled form (assuming it's compiled with Linux style mangling convention - which android does - but if you were to take a Microsoft compiled piece of code, it clearly wouldn't work).

If you compile with debug symbols, gdb should be able to show you the source for a given piece of code. Add `-g` to the `g++` line in the compile.

Comment: Thank you for the information Mats. can you please answer tp my comment underneath my question? It would be helpful

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you can find some place in `android.mk` or one of its dependencies. Unfortunately, I don't know exactly where/how to do that. Probably easiest to search for the name of the function (`grep -r CameraHardware::createInstance *` in some place that holds the source code of the Android system), and then see if there is a makefile somewhere "nearby" that covers that source file.